# I have type " sudo sensors-detect" and my display become muddy

Tags: command-line, kernel

I am using Lenovo Z 50-70 laptop with i5 4210U processor.
I type `sudo sensors-detect` and yes to all options. This make my display muddy. How can I get back to default configuration.

Using Ubuntu 14.04